# file upload using angularjs without $scope

Tags: angularjs

Am new to Angular and im trying to implement Logo upload using angular 1. After choosing the file if i hit upload its showing as undefined. Please help.

Here is my HTML code:

```
 <input type="file" data-file-model="organisationCtrl.filesArray" >
                        <button type="submit" data-ng-click="organisationCtrl.uploadFile()">save</button>
```

Here is the Angular Part:
//main Controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('vyahara').controller('OrganisationCtrl', OrganisationCtrl);
    // The $inject property is an array of service names to inject.
    OrganisationCtrl.$inject = [ '$http', '$window', '$location',  '$rootScope',
            'GenericPostService' ];
    function OrganisationCtrl($http, $window, $location, $rootScope,
            GenericPostService) {
        var organisationCtrl = this;
```

//UserName Validation (for understanding) which is working fine:

```
organisationCtrl.validUser = validUser;
        function validUser()
        {
            console.log("sdagfsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg");
            if (organisationCtrl.userName != null
                    && organisationCtrl.userName != "") {
                if (organisationCtrl.userName.length < 8) {
                    swal('', 'User Id must have 8-15 Chracters', 'warning');
                    organisationCtrl.userName = "";
                }
                var userCreationBean = {
                    "userCreationBean" : {
                        userNumber : organisationCtrl.userName,
                    }
                }
                GenericPostService
                        .post('/user/valid/search', userCreationBean)
                        .then(
                                function(response) {
                                    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                                        swal('', 'User Name Already Taken',
                                                'warning');
                                        organisationCtrl.userName = "";

                                    } else {
                                        organisationCtrl.userName = organisationCtrl.userName;
                                    }

                                });

            }
        }
```

//file Upload Not working

```
organisationCtrl.uploadFile = uploadFile;
        function uploadFile() {

                var fileUpload = new FormData();
                console.log("You are In!!!!",organisationCtrl.filesArray);
                fileUpload.append("fileUpload", organisationCtrl.filesArray);
                console.log(">>>>>>>>>>",fileUpload);
                GenericPostService.postWithConfig('/organization/createFile',  fileUpload, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
                })
                .then(
                        function(response) {
                            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                                swal('', 'File Upload Successful');
```

});

Answer (score 0):

There are many Angularjs modules to perform file uploading, you just have to include them in your code .That way you won't complicate the code. Below are some links you can refer to:

https://github.com/leon/angular-upload

https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

https://github.com/radify/angular-file

http://www.folio3.com/blog/angularjs-file-upload-example-tutorial/

or you can simply go ahead by-->

```
npm install ng-file-upload
```

include some script tags

```
<script src="angular(.min).js"></script>
<script src="ng-file-upload-shim(.min).js"></script> <!-- for no html5 browsers support -->
<script src="ng-file-upload(.min).js"></script>


Upload on form submit or button click
<form ng-app="fileUpload" ng-controller="MyCtrl" name="form">
  Single Image with validations
  <div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="file" name="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
    ngf-accept="'image/*'" ngf-max-size="20MB" ngf-min-height="100" 
    ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}">Select</div>
  Multiple files
  <div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="files" ngf-multiple="true">Select</div>
  Drop files: <div ngf-drop ng-model="files" class="drop-box">Drop</div>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">submit</button>
</form>

Upload right away after file selection:
<div class="button" ngf-select="upload($file)">Upload on file select</div>
<div class="button" ngf-select="uploadFiles($files)" multiple="multiple">Upload on file select</div>
  Drop File:
<div ngf-drop="uploadFiles($files)" class="drop-box"
  ngf-drag-over-class="'dragover'" ngf-multiple="true" 
  ngf-pattern="'image/*,application/pdf'">Drop Images or PDFs files here</div>
<div ngf-no-file-drop>File Drag/Drop is not supported for this browser</div>

Image thumbnail: <img ngf-thumbnail="file || '/thumb.jpg'">
Audio preview: <audio controls ngf-src="file"></audio>
Video preview: <video controls ngf-src="file"></video>
```

Comment: Hey Johnbet..thanks for the suggestion..But can u be more specific about controller part.?I am not clear as im new for Angular.